# (IONIC) Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dataServicesProvider <- dataServices <- AuthCtrl

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Im not able to connect to a custom service (dataService) which i had made.
here is the controller code

```
angular.module('auth.controller', [])
.controller('AuthCtrl',function($scope, $state, $ionicHistory, dataService) {
//some code 
});
```

here is my custom service

```
angular.module('data.service',[])
    .service('dataService', ['$http',function ($http) {
//some code
}])
```

my main controller

```
angular.module('wgmsApp.controllers', ['auth.controller','dashboard.controller')
.controller('MenuCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $state){
    }])
```

my service.js

```
angular.module('wgmsApp.services', ['data.service'])
```

All files are included properly in index.html

Comment: There's a typo in service name while injecting. Also modules creation and passing have issues.

Comment: Youve got allot of syntax issues there but i presume there from the copy and paste job. Also `$scope` is not inject-able other than in controllers, your trying to add it to a service.

Comment: @Diljohn5741 i have corrected it but still im getting same error

Comment: @ste2425 checkout now i have edited..and yea dont go on syntax  error

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the service `dataService` as part of the module `data.service`.

Therefore, to be able to leverage the *services* of one particular module in another, you'll need to inject the former into the latter.

i.e.

```
angular.module('auth.controller', ['data.service']) // inject the `data.service` module here
   .controller('AuthCtrl',function($scope, $state, $ionicHistory, dataService) {
   //some code 
});
```

Comment: BTW, you're also welcome to Stack Overflow.
@NishilBhave, also note that the preferred way of saying _thanks_ in Stackoverflow is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (in case you have enough reputation) and by accepting useful/helpful answers to any question you ask, which would in turn help others quickly find solutions to their problems similar to yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to use like this-

```
   angular.module('auth.controller', [])
    .controller('AuthCtrl',["$scope","$state","$ionicHistory","dataService",function($scope, $state, $ionicHistory, dataService) {
    //some code 
    }]);
```

Hope this may help you.